# Eliminar espacio entre dos print

Tags: python, python-2.x, print

¿Cómo puedo eliminar el espacio entre 2 `print` distintos en Python? Por ejemplo:

```
num = raw_input()
num = float(num)
result=""
while num>=1000:
    result+= "M"
    num = num - 1000
if num>=900:
    result+= "CM",
    num=num-900
if num>=500:
    result+= "D",
    num=num-500
if num>=400:
    result+= "CD",
    num=num-400
while num>=100:
    result+= "C",
    num=num-100
if num>=90:
    result+= "XC",
    num=num-90
if num>=50:
    result+= "L",
    num=num-50
if num>=40:
    result+= "XL",
    num=num-40
while num>=10:
    result+= "X",
    num=num-10
if num == 9:
    result+= "IX",
    num=num-9
if num>=5:
    result+= "V",
    num=num-5
if num>=4:
    result+= "IV",
    num=num-4
while num>0:
    result+= "I",
    num=num-1  

print result
```

Me lo imprime así:

> D C

pero yo lo quiero así:

> DC

---

> **NOTA:** si les saco la coma al final me los devuelve uno abajo del otro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opcion es ir concatenando el resultado en una variable `result` tipo string, asi puedes construir el `string` como desees (insertar cualquier simbolo o espacio).

```
num = raw_input()
num = float(num)
result=""
while num>=1000:
    result+= "M"
    num = num - 1000
if num>=900:
    result+= "CM"
    num=num-900
if num>=500:
    result+= "D"
    num=num-500
if num>=400:
    result+= "CD"
    num=num-400
while num>=100:
    result+= "C"
    num=num-100
if num>=90:
    result+= "XC"
    num=num-90
if num>=50:
    result+= "L"
    num=num-50
if num>=40:
    result+= "XL"
    num=num-40
while num>=10:
    result+= "X"
    num=num-10
if num == 9:
    result+= "IX"
    num=num-9
if num>=5:
    result+= "V"
    num=num-5
if num>=4:
    result+= "IV"
    num=num-4
while num>0:
    result+= "I"
    num=num-1  

print result
```

En caso de que entre a ambos ifs, entonces el output seria asi:

> CMD

Comment: probe esta opcion y me da el siguiente error "typeError: cannot concatenate "str" and "tuple" objects "

Comment: @Miled estas seguro de que estas utilizando el mismo codigo? o intentas hacer algo mas?, edita tu pregunta y muestra el codigo que estas utilizando que te da error para ver que intentas hacer.

Comment: aca te lo dejo como me dijiste:

Comment: @Miled debes eliminar las comas luego de concatenar el string, si quieres incluir la coma, debes hacerlo dentro de las comillas. Por ejemplo `result += "CM,"` si lo haces asi `result += "CM",` te dara error. Lo ideal es que lo hagas asi: `result += "CM"` eliminando la coma. Dejame saber si te funciona.

Comment: si! ya me dio bien, muchas gracias andres!

Answer (score 1):

Podrias intentar con el comando **end** que permite variar las impresiones de tu codigo asi:

```
from __future__ import print_function
num=2000
if num>=900:
    print ('CM',end='')
    num=num-900
if num>=500:
    print ("D")
    num=num-500

output:
CMD
```

> **Nota** el ***from __future__ import print_function*** es para que no marque error de sintaxis ya que esta función sirve es en python 3.7

Comment: me da error y no me deja ejecutarlo

Comment: que error te da?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias opciones:

- **Usar `sys.stdout` en vez de `print`**:

  ```
  import sys

  sys.stdout.write("D")
  sys.stdout.write("C")
  ```
- **Pasarte a Python 3 o usar `print` de éste en Python 2**.

  Esto se debe a que en Python 3 [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) es una función y tiene los parámetros `end` (carácter a añadir al final del `print`, nueva línea por defecto) y `sep` (carácter a añadir entre objetos a imprimir dentro de una misma llamada de `print`) que te permiten hacer justo lo que quieres:

  ```
  from __future__ import print_function

  print("D", end='')
  print("C", end='')
  ```

Si quieres imprimir una serie de objetos con un separador propio o sin ninguno entre ellos, pero usando un solo `print` también puedes usar [formateo de cadenas](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) o [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) por ejemplo:

```
>>> letras = ("H", "o", "l", "a")
>>> print "".join(letras)
Hola
>>> print "{}{}{}{}".format(*letras)
Hola

>>> hora = "2"
>>> min = "15"
>>> sec = "58"
>>> print '{}:{}:{}'.format(hora, min, sec)
2:15:58
>>> print '%d:%d:%d' % (hora, min, sec)
2:15:58
```

Answer (score 0):

Para python3,
con sep=(''), no se bien si sirva pero aqui un ejemplo de como funciona sep=('') (no es el mejor ejemplo pero sirve):

```
a=2
for i in range(1,5):
    s=i*a
    print(s,'+',end=('')) #esto imprime 2 +4 +6 +8 +
```

si se usa el sep=('') de esta manera entonces:

```
a=2
for i in range(1,5):
    s=i*a
    print(s,'+',end=(''),sep=('')) #esto imprime 2+4+6+8+
```

Notese que, sin el end=('') se imprimirian los numeros y un + separado, uno sobre otro (diferente renglon), el end solo imprime sin saltos de impresion (en el mismo renglon), el sep quita los espacios entre los valores a imprimir